Invalid initial heap size error in Android Studio
I hope you can help me with the following error Android Studio IDE:
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms1024m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

This error occurs when I Increase heap size in Edit Custom VM Options with the following code:
-Xms1024m       
-Xmx4096m       
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops

after reset laptop and starting Android Studio i got the error message as above
I tried asking chatgpt to help me fix the above error by reconfiguring the **studio64.exe.vmoptions ** file with the following minimum options:
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea

but the result is still not possible
